# verilog always @(posedge) failing in uart

Tags: verilog

I'm learning verilog and I think there is something that I must not understand about always @* and always (@posedge clk, ...)

Here is a piece of code supposed to send bits via uart. It fails at synthesization.
The error is 
" The logic for  does not match a known FF or Latch template. The description style you are using to describe a register or latch is not supported in the current software release."
(and 3 other errors for ,  and )
If I change the always @(...) by always @*, things fail in the next step ("implement design") because things are not connected.

In the book that I have, they implement an fsmd with an always (posedge clk) for the state, and always @* for the other logic, but I don't understand why this doesn't work.

On another forum, I read that the error could come from too complicated conditions. But I have simplified things too (not code the code here but basically I removed the case(state) and the ifs to have single line assignments with ? : or binary conditions, but it didn't work either)

I have seen this error before in other pieces of code that I wrote but I didn't get to the bottom of it, so if you could help me understand the general problem (with this uart thing as a support for a concrete example), I would be very happy.
Thanks
Thomas

P.S : Im using xilinx spartan 3e starter kit and xilinx ise 14.4

```
module UART_out #(parameter [3:0] NUM_BITS = 8)
(
input wire baud_clk,
input wire send_tick,
input wire[NUM_BITS-1:0] data_in,
output wire tx,
output wire debug_done
);
localparam
        IDLE = 0,
        TRANSMIT = 1;
reg[NUM_BITS:0] bits_to_send;
reg state;
reg out_bit;
reg[4:0] cnt;

always @(posedge baud_clk, posedge send_tick)
begin
    case (state)
    IDLE:
        if (send_tick)
        begin
            bits_to_send <= {data_in, 0};
            state <= TRANSMIT;
            cnt <= 0;
        end
    TRANSMIT:
        begin
            if (cnt < NUM_BITS)
                cnt <= cnt + 1;
            else
                state <= IDLE;
            bits_to_send <= {1, bits_to_send[NUM_BITS:1]};
            out_bit <= bits_to_send[0];
        end
    endcase
end

assign tx = (state == IDLE ? 1 : out_bit);
assign debug_done = (state == IDLE);    
endmodule
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error:

```
The logic for does not match a known FF or Latch template. The description style you are using to describe a register or latch is not supported in the current software release.
```

Is referring to the fact that the synthesis tool does not have any hardware cells to use which match your description.

What hardware do you want from :

```
always @(posedge baud_clk, posedge send_tick)
```

This looks like you want a flip-flop with an enable signal. The enable signal (send_tick) should be 1 clock period wide. This is then used to select the path of logic on a clock edge. not as an alternative trigger.

I think that this is all you really need:

```
always @(posedge baud_clk) begin
  case (state)
    IDLE:
      if (send_tick) begin
        //...
      end
     //...
   endcase
end
```

If `send_tick` is from another clock domain then you will need to do some clock domain crossing to turn it it to a clock wide pulse on the `baud_clk`.

You may be getting confused with blocks which have multiple triggers, they are normally a clk and reset. A `negedge reset_n` or `posedge reset` are often added for reset (initialisation) conditions.

If adding a reset :

```
always @(posedge baud_clk or negedge reset_n) begin
  if (~reset_n) begin
    //reset conditions
    state <= IDLE;
    //...
  end
  else begin
    // Standard logic
  end
end
```

You will notice that there is a very definite structure here, if reset else ... The synthesis tools recognise this as a flip-flop with an asynchronous reset. The data in the reset condition is also static, typically setting everything to zero.